# How to diagnose a SSH remote port forward not working

Tags: networking, ssh

Using the command `ssh -v -R 2255:localhost:2255 root@example.com` I was trying to figure out why remote port forwarding wasn't working until I realized `GatewayPorts yes` was not present in my host's sshd_config. Once I added that, it worked successfully.

Is there a way I could have diagnosed this?

The SSH even output the following (without  `GatewayPorts yes`):

```
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:2255 forwarded to local address localhost:2255
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 2255, connect localhost:2255
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

Comment: You can't diagnose everything from the client, you frequently need to check from the server (sometimes after increasing the verbosity   to a sufficient debug level there as well)

Comment: Surely there exists some means to verify that packets are being forwarded or not.

Answer (score 12):

You need `GatewayPorts yes` in sshd_config to be able to access it from outside.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`

Comment: Found in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: I feel really dumb now after realising it. Do take note that the hash `#` symbol before a line in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` refers to a comment, so remember to uncomment the line to allow the `GatewayPorts` config to work.

Answer (score 5):

When you specify `2255:localhost:2255` fills the missing hostname in front as a `localhost`. This will really bind only to `localhost` address (loopback). If you want to use it also "from outside", you need to use the server IP for the remote port forwarding, such as `example.com:2255:localhost:2255`.

Comment: I'm not too sure where I imply that I'd like to access this "from outside"?

Comment: To `localhost`, you can connecton only from that machine (and not from any other). To the IP of that server, you can connect also from other machines in the network.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "not working" in the question, but this *could* be the case.

Comment: `localhost` is `lo` interface on `example.com`

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy yes. And so what?

Comment: By not working I mean requests to remote, were not being forwarded to the client I was remote port forwarding.

Comment: How do you issue the requests? From that machine or from different one? See the edit. It is hopefully more clear.

Comment: It shouldn't matter from where the requests come from?

Comment: It really does in case you bind only to `localhost`.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add more `-v`s to make the output even more verbose. OpenSSH supports up to three `v`s:

```sh
ssh -vvv
```

Level three verbose output should include information about port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to diagnose this today I'd probably have a look at tcpdump:

`tcpdump  -v -i any tcp port 2255 -A`.

Comment: Why this? I try and see gibberish...

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for me were both the answers of [Jakuje](https://serverfault.com/a/851161/509399) and [noraj](https://serverfault.com/a/980910/509399) combind:

1. You need to specify the remote bind address in addition to the remote port to `-R` (i.e.  `-R '*:$REMOTEPORT:$LOCALADDR:$LOCALPORT'`). If you don't specify the address, sshd will only bind to the loopback interface (by default).
2. By default, it seems, `/etc/sshd_confing`'s `GatewayPorts` [defaults to no]. You should set it to `yes` to **forcefully** expose forwarded ports or `clientspecified` to allow the client to choose. I prefer the latter.

Once set, my server exposed the forwarded service as expected.

If you're still having trouble, you can check how `sshd` is actually binding the external port (e.g. `ss -a`) and whether the exposed port is being blocked by a local or upstream firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `sudo netstat -a | grep 2255` and `sshd -T` It shows me now:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:2255         *:*                     LISTEN
```

So it still binds to localhost even I did `ssh -R server_ip:2255:localhost2255 server_ip`.

`sshd -T | grep -i gatewayports` shows gateway ports set to `no`, which might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have already added '-v' option to enable diagnostics. Now your ssh client will print something like this whenever a connection request is received and then forwarded,

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 3311, originator 49.36.238.183 port 39234
debug1: connect_next: host 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:3308) in progress, fd=7
debug1: channel 1: new [49.36.238.183]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to 127.0.0.1 port 3308
debug1: channel 1: free: 49.36.238.183, nchannels 2
```

And if the GatewayPorts is set to 'no' then the client will print nothing.